# The import org.testng cannot be resolved with maven

Tags: java, maven, testng

I'm trying to launch TestNG tests with maven, but errors occurs:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:2.0.0:compile (default-compile) on project auto-test.headless.connections: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] C:\Users\pooor\git\dbeaver-qa-auto\auto-test\headless\connections\src\connections\test\FactoryRunner.java:[3]
[ERROR]         import org.testng.ITest;
[ERROR]                ^^^^^^^^^^
```

There is no problems with launching in Eclipse or IntelliJIDEA.
I've already tried cleaning the .m2 folder and using other versions of testng. Nothing works for me.
Here is my pom:

Comment: pom is too long then can't be attached. the most necessary info i think that packaging is set like that: <packaging>eclipse-test-plugin</packaging>. Dependencies for testng I took from the maven central repository and did not specify anything else regarding testng in the pom. maybe I need to connect more features?

Comment: any reason you are not following standard maven directory layout?

Comment: I don't know :/ I am new to the company.I was given a structure, and I did not argue. But in general, now I have changed the structure to the standard one for maven projects - unfortunately nothing has changed

Comment: Ask a senior developer to help you set up your computer properly.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be using testng outside test sources, do you import it with the right scope ?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>  
</dependency>
```

Although if this class is indeed a test class, you need to follow [Maven's standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and move it in a package under **src/test/java**. You should then be able to compile with

```
<scope>test</scope>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to move the test class from src/ into test/ ?

Comment: Already tried to change scope. Also i tried moving the tests into a folder as you said. nothing has changed, except that now the maven is trying to execute tests with the 'test' parameter